# Separating code from for function while using values within for function in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Sorry for the confusing title :s

```
for x in frequency:
        alphab = [x]
        frequencies = [frequency[x]]
        print alphab, frequencies
```

How would I be able to separate the below code from the above code whilst still using the output from `for x in frequency:` If I run what's here, the histogram is opened for each value of x rather than the whole string. 
If I indent anything below, as seen here, the histogram only runs for the first value of x as well.
Is there any possible way to use the entire string without having the histogram function indented within `for`

```
pos = np.arange(len(alphab))
width = 1.0     

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
ax.set_xticklabels(alphab)
plt.xlabel('Letter')
plt.ylabel('Absolute Frequency')
plt.title("Absolute Frequency of letters in text")
plt.bar(pos, frequencies, width, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think anyone actually gets what you're looking for...

Comment: Isn't it already separated? You have to explain more precisely what you want to do.

Comment: which one is your entire string and where is histogram? Sorry, too difficult to comprehend and wrong tagging too. ( I am correcting it)

Answer (score 0):

```
def plotfreq(frequency, alphab):

    pos = np.arange(len(alphab))
    width = 1.0     

    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
    ax.set_xticklabels(alphab)
    plt.xlabel('Letter')
    plt.ylabel('Absolute Frequency')
    plt.title("Absolute Frequency of letters in text")
    plt.bar(pos, frequency, width, color='r')
    plt.show()

for x in frequencies:

    plotfreq(x, frequencies[x])
```

Is this something you were looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to populate the arrays before calling the plot function, e.g.

```
alphab = []
frequencies = []
for x in frequency:
        alphab.append(x)
        frequencies.append(frequency[x])

# .. some more code here ..
plt.bar(pos, frequencies, width, color='r')
```